# Validate source parameter with typescript in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I was wondering if it was possible (at the moment) to validate what is transmitted in the source property of inputs/fields.

I generate types (typescript) from my graphql introspection schema and I use it when I retrieve the controller so it would be awesome if typescript could validate that the source really exists in my record.

Example :

```js
    type Organisation {
       id: number;
       name: string;
    }
    
    
    const OrganisationShow = (props: ShowProps) => {
      const { record, ...controllerProps } = useShowController<Organisation>(props);
    
      return (
        <ShowView
          record={record}
          {...controllerProps}
        >
           <TextField source="id" />
           <TextField source="name" />
           <TextField source="foo" /> // Typescript should deny it
       </ShowView>
      )
    }
```

Is this something possible or an idea ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible for now. You would have to pass the type to all fields (`<TextField<Organization> source="id" />`, so I don't think it's very developer-friendly. And for nested source (e.g. `author.name`), I don't think it's feasible.